# Height of Owl Carousel on phone

Tags: css, flexbox, owl-carousel

I have an image which covers the entire screen on a desktop using Owl Carousel.

When i view the same image on a phone device it takes up only 1 third of the screen size.

How could i adjust the height so its taller than what it currently is on a phone?

I've read a few threads but being new with Owl carousel im not sure if i've done something wrong. I couldnt find this class https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/owl-slider-100-height/ so not sure

My config for Owl carousel is

```
            items: 1,
            smartSpeed: 1000,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 6000,
            dots: false,
            loop: true,
            mouseDrag: false,
            autoHeight:false,
            touchDrag: false,
            autoHeight:true
```

Owl Carousel v2.3.4

CSS Used (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css )

```
/**
 * Owl Carousel v2.3.4
 * Copyright 2013-2018 David Deutsch
 * Licensed under: SEE LICENSE IN https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/master/LICENSE
 */

.owl-carousel,
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative
}

.owl-carousel {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    position: relative;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item,
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled {
    display: none
}

.no-js .owl-carousel,
.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    display: block
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dot,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev,
.owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
    background: 0 0;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0!important;
    font: inherit
}

.owl-carousel.owl-loading {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block
}

.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
    opacity: 0
}

.owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item {
    visibility: hidden
}

.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}

.owl-carousel.owl-grab {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: grab
}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
    direction: rtl
}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
    float: right
}

.owl-carousel .animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both
}

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-in {
    z-index: 0
}

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-out {
    z-index: 1
}

.owl-carousel .fadeOut {
    animation-name: fadeOut
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

.owl-height {
    transition: height .5s ease-in-out
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s ease
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy:not([src]),
.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy[src^=""] {
    max-height: 0
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img.owl-lazy {
    transform-style: preserve-3d
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    background: url(owl.video.play.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .1s ease
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3, 1.3)
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-play-icon,
.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-tn {
    display: none
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-tn {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    transition: opacity .4s ease
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-frame {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: This may require some playing around with the CSS. For example, height: 100vh; on the container of the carousel. And clearly test it on the various browsers you are testing for!

Saving that, check that there are no other styles affecting the container. The content - image - of the container may be dictating the size of the container so it would make sense to be smaller given the container would adjust to the contents aspect ratio.

Comment: This tutorial may be what you are looking for: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-full-screen-responsive-carousel-slider-with-owljs--cms-31771

Comment: @KurtisRogers Thanks and i think you're correct. I've added the CSS i imported above (with a link from the demo i copied it from). Im having the exact same problem as this page https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html - if you resize the browser or go into dev mode and select a phone device you will see how the colour only takes up a portion of the space - i would like it full height. Michael_Eugene_Yuen I looked at that link but it looks like its using Bootstrap which im not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've gathered, you want the container to be full height and full width on Desktop and Mobile using Owl Carousel.

I made a Pen for you which may help you on your way to getting where you want to get to with Owl Carousel - I don't know much about it as I tend not to use Carousels any more but it is a good solution for carousels!

https://codepen.io/kurtis-rogers/full/NozyEz

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Owl Carousel 2 Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="post-content-parent">
      <div class="c--post-content-image-wrapper"></div>
      <div class="post-content-text-child">
        <div class="post-content--inner">
          <h2>Slider 1</h2>
          <p>Some information about slider 1</p>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Read more">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content-parent">
      <div class="c--post-content-image-wrapper"></div>
      <div class="post-content-text-child">
        <div class="post-content--inner">
          <h2>Slider 1</h2>
          <p>Some information about slider 1</p>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Read more">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS(SCSS):

```
body, html{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.owl-carousel, .owl-stage-outer {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

// Parent container for the images and text
.post-content-parent{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

// Post content image styles
.c--post-content-image-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/132037/pexels-photo-132037.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

// Post text content
.post-content-text-child{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  .post-content--inner {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  h2, p {
    margin: 0;
  }
  input[type="button"] {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 1,
    center: true,
    lazyLoad: true,
    dots: false
  });
});
```

If you need any help with this let me know :)

Comment: Thanks will check this out. Appreciate your help. Just curious but the other way I've seen this done on other sites is they have a large image and on a phone the left as right side of the image is cropped. So the full image is only shown on the desktop version. Is this what you do?

Comment: It's literally CSS background image on the containers within each Owl slide. You can accomplish this in the template of most CMS'/frameworks meaning it can be done dynamically rather than statically within the CSS file. The background position takes care of the image positioning along with background-size: cover; - the image isn't cropped, it's literally just a background image :)

Comment: I added the above code (but converted to CSS). I see the image however if i view this on a desktop the image is full but on a mobile its only showing the centre of the image. Is this intended or optional? Thx

Comment: Hi Computer - you could probably edit the background position and size for mobile using some css for the mobile view only but this would be a huge headache if you had to change this per every image added to get the intended mobile display of the image - instead, you should recommend to your client or manager that every image used for the carousel in the future should be the same size and that each image looks almost the same i.e. a person or a product is in the same place each time. This becomes more of a discussion based on content decision making instead :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because the aspect ratio of desktop screen and mobile screen are not same.

The best way is to use two different sets of images for desktop and mobile. You can show landscape images for desktop and portrait images for mobile.

You can try with HTML picture element to show different images on desktop and mobile:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

Comment: If i use this method i dont think the images would slide as they do with an Owl slider.