# Images on an owl carousel are zoomed in on mobile, how do I change it so that it displays all of the image on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

**This is how it looks on a desktop:**

[image]

**This is how it looks on mobile:**

[image]

I have the standard properties for the carousel (its nothing special, just a slideshow). I just want it to scale and show the whole picture on mobile instead of zooming in on random parts.

**HTML**

```
<div class="home-banner">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme home-slider">
        <div class="item pro_nw" style="background-image: url({{asset('public/frontend/images/slide1_v4.jpg')}});">
        </div>
        <div class="item pro_nw" style="background-image: url({{asset('public/frontend/images/slider-2.jpg')}});">
        </div>
        <div class="item pro_nw" style="background-image: url({{asset('public/frontend/images/slider-3.jpg')}});">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.home-slider{position: relative;}
.home-slider,
.home-slider .owl-stage-outer,
.home-slider .owl-stage-outer .owl-stage,
.home-slider .owl-stage-outer .owl-stage .owl-item,
.home-slider .owl-stage-outer .owl-stage .owl-item .item{height: 100%;}
.home-slider .owl-stage-outer .owl-stage .owl-item .item{
    position: relative;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    justify-content:center;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 730px;
}
```

It has to be one of the properties in the CSS (i think). I played around with a few of the properties, but it scales in odd ways instead.

Answer (score 0):

for mobile media query make sure to change background-size to contain.
keep the original size for the screen wider than a mobile screen.

Answer (score 0):

First change the background size to contain.

```
background-size: contain;
```

then detect the actual screen of the device as to adjust the image size corresponding to your liking

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {      
    .home-slider .owl-stage-outer .owl-stage .owl-item .item{      
        //size you wanted 
      //for example---
       width: 50%;
       height: 50%;
    
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried this, changed the width and height to different values, including 100% on both. But this keeps happening https://imgur.com/a/6Sigp5N

Comment: Hi, I think you need a lot of tampering with css to achieve the right size, try changing the 

`width: auto` or
`height : 100vh`

Also, I have seen somebody with the same problem as you in this link

[Height of Owl Carousel on phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595413/height-of-owl-carousel-on-phone)

and this codepen below made by Sir @Kurtis Rogers  on the same page is, I think the way you wanted to achieve for your page

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kurtis-rogers/full/NozyEz)

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I'll look into it :)

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

for mobile responsive make use of media query depending on the screen

```
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) /* specify preferred width here*/
{
/*statement*/
}
```